# Caption element and 100% width on nested tables

Tags: html, css, firefox, caption, accessibility

I'm using `caption` on a `table` that includes children table elements.
Within the caption element I've got a `div` incl. two links that should be on the right edge of the uppermost table.
But as soon as I'm defining `display: block;` besides `position: relative;` on caption, it's size is shrinking to the first child table cell's width.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/zjFmv/

The important CSS selectors:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1.8rem;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

caption {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F5F5;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1rem 1.4rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* Variations */
.caption-01 {
    position: relative;
}
.caption-02 {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.caption-03 {
    display: table-header-group;
}

caption div {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    top: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Is there a way to let the div be on right edge of caption at full primary table width in my construct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you remove `display:block`

Comment: Have you had a look into my jsfiddle? With `position: relative;` alone the absolute positioned buttons are not displayed within the caption.

Comment: @Mark Actually your question brought another idea up: Giving `table { position: relative; }`. Then it work's. Still caption display doesn't seem right to me. Updated http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/zjFmv/5/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the display properties form caption 2 & 3

```
.caption-02 {
    position: relative;
}
.caption-03 {
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBndp/)

Comment: You've just used my jsfiddle from my second comment…?! What's your part of the answer?

Comment: No, if you take out `display` properties & table's `position: relative;` it's *not* working: http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/zjFmv/6/

Comment: @VolkerE. right - and add `position:relative` to `table` - like I have in my [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBndp/) and that should do it.